# Corrutinas en Kotlin: Scopes

Tags: kotlin, corrutinas

Estoy haciendo un curso de corrutinas para Kotlin y me han surgido unas cuantas dudas en cuanto al scope. En primer lugar entiendo que el `GlobalScope` va ligado al ciclo de vida, si el activity (por ejemplo) muere antes de que la corrutina termine, lanza excepción, corregidme si me equivoco.

También me he encontrado con dos formas de implementar `CoroutineScope`, una seria directamente implementar la interfaz y llamar al get pasandole el Dispatcher y el job, y la otra que he visto es creando una instancia de esta, ¿qué diferencia existe?

Por último la otra duda que tengo es el método `MainScope` que lo he visto usar en algunos casos como `MainScope().launch` y por lo que he visto ya te proporciona una `CoroutineScope`, pero, ¿cuando uso uno u otro? ¿Qué es mejor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> En primer lugar entiendo que el `GlobalScope` va ligado al ciclo de
> vida, si el activity (por ejemplo) muere antes de que la corrutina
> termine, lanza excepción, corregidme si me equivoco.

Está ligado al ciclo de vida **de la aplicación**, no del Activity. Por esa razón se aconseja NO usarlo para crear coroutines. Si se cierra el Activity la coroutine seguirá en ejecución, y seguirá en ejecución hasta que se cierre la aplicación.

> También me he encontrado con dos formas de implementar `CoroutineScope`,
> una seria directamente implementar la interfaz y llamar al get
> pasandole el Dispatcher y el job, y la otra que he visto es creando
> una instancia de esta, ¿que diferencia existe?

Es prácticamente lo mismo con la diferencia de que si implementas la interfaz no necesitas hacer referencia al Scope para crear una coroutine porque la instancia de la clase en sí (`this`) ya funciona como Scope.

Implementando la interfaz:

```
class MiClase: CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Default

    fun miTarea() = launch {

    }
    
}
```

Implementando la interface delegando:

```
class MiClase: CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {
    
    fun miTarea() = launch {

    }
}
```

Creando una instancia:

```
class MiClase {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    
    fun miTarea() = scope.launch {
    
    }
}
```

> Por último la otra duda que tengo es el método `MainScope` que lo he
> visto usar en algunos casos como `MainScope().launch` y por lo que he
> visto ya te proporciona una `CoroutineScope`, pero, ¿cuando uso uno u
> otro? ¿Qué es mejor?

Cuando usas el método de fábrica `MainScope()` para crear un Scope es prácticamente lo mismo que crearlo de esta manera: `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main)`. Aquí lo importante más allá de cómo crear un Scope es cómo los referenciarás luego para cuando necesites cancelar las coroutines que están aún en ejecución. Si empiezas a crear Scopes cada vez que quieras iniciar una coroutine ej. `MainScope().launch {...}` o `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {...}` no podrás cancelarlas y sería prácticamente lo mismo que crearlas con GlobalScope.

Lo más sano siempre será mantener la referencia hacia el Scope para poder cancelar las coroutines cuando sea necesario (por ejemplo durante `onDestroy()` de un Activity) aprovechando la concurrencia estructurada para no tener que cancelar todas y cada una de las coroutines creadas una por una, sino hacerlo cancelando el Scope (o el Job del Scope) del que se tiene referencia.

Comment: Una duda, cuando implementas la interfaz delegada, no es necesario el job? Y cuando creas una instancia veo que tampoco lo has usado.

Comment: @Ludiras En realidad no hace falta porque cada vez que creas una coroutine implícitamente se crea un Job que termina siendo hijo del Job de la coroutine madre. Técnicamente hablando cuando no implementas la interfaz por delegación es común que crees un Job y lo uses en el contexto y que termines usando la referencia hacia ese Job para cancelar todo.

Comment: @Ludiras También debes tomar en cuenta que cada vez que le pases un Job al contexto se rompe la relación padre-hijo entre el Job de la nueva coroutine y el Job de la coroutine madre y por lo tanto pierdes la concurrencia estructurada. El Job de la coroutine que creaste termina siendo hijo del Job que le pasaste en el contexto. Puedes acceder al Job del Scope con el que estás trabajando así `this.coroutineContext[Job]` en caso de haber implementado la interfaz o `scope.coroutineContext[Job]` si usas una instancia.

Comment: Y otra duda más, si estoy en una clase repositorio, ¿como uso los jobs en esta clase? Entiendo que puedo iniciarlo, pero para finalizarlo? Aquí no tengo métodos onDestroy()

Comment: @Ludiras No crees coroutines en esa capa. Implementa la funcionalidad con funciones `suspend`. Las coroutines se crean en la capa View y en el ViewModel o Presenter. No vayas mas allá sino se te va a hacer un lío y empezarás a ver memory leaks por todas partes. Las cancelaciones se harán entonces en `onDestroy` o en `onCleared`. En todos caso si lo llegaras a hacer, crea un método que se llame parecido y lo llamas desde esos dos métodos. O haz tu repositorio LifecycleAware, pero como puedes imaginar todo se empieza a liar.

Comment: Vale, tomo nota entonces, pues muchas gracias, doy la respuesta como solución :)

Comment: Miento, última duda: me has dicho que no cree corrutinas dentro de este tipo de clases sino funciones de suspensión, pero en el caso de que quiera crear otro hilo dentro de la función de suspensión si estaría bien usar witchContext?

Comment: @Ludiras Es muy extraño que quieras crear otro hilo dentro de una función `suspend`, si lo llegas a hacer estarías haciendo más de una cosa dentro de la función y probablemente debas dividir la tarea y que los resultados se encuentren dentro del cuerpo de la coroutine en la capa del ViewModel o del View. Usa `withContext` para cambiar de `Dispatcher` cuando lo requieras, ya sea dentro del cuerpo de la coroutine o dentro de la función `suspend`, `withContext` lo puedes usar a discreción, no se crea otro subproceso cuando lo haces.